# Most elegant way to terminate straced program

Tags: shell, shell-script, process, strace

I want to capture a certain thing with strace and then immediately exit. This way the program stays alive: `strace ... program 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered ... | read line`.

Is there a simple way to make strace kill the program after strace itself is terminated?

This is how I workaround it:

```
(strace ... program 2>&1 & echo $! >&3) 3>pid | grep --line-buffered ... | while read line; do
    kill `<pid`
    break
done
```

But it doesn't look very nice.

**UPD:**

Turned out that the actual problem is that the program I trace ignores SIGPIPE. I guess clean way to workaround this is to create an additional layer that intercepts SIGPIPE and sends SIGTERM instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your grep supports it, you can use `grep -m 1 ...` to get it to stop after it has found the match. This will cause the pipe to close and the strace to die, assuming it continues to write.

Comment: That's my problem, in the first command strace does exit, it's just the traced program doesn't. It ignores SIGPIPE and becomes orphaned.